# Can't access rest api method when Codeigniter app in sub folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, vhosts

I have problem accessing my REST api methods when I put my Codeigniter app in subfolder. I have placed Codeigniter app inside rest folder. Then I try to call `http://myapp.dev/rest/api/Workingday/workingDay` and I get 404 not found, same problem appears if I try to visit `http://myapp.dev/rest/index.php`

This is my folder structure

[image]

And this is my extenden rest api folder, so you can see that I have api folder in controllers and there will be public and rest APIs.

[image]

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rest/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

And this is my vhost on Apache server (localhost development)
NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.dev
    ServerAlias *.myapp.dev
    ServerAdmin info@myapp.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/user/workspace/myapp" LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "/Users/user/workspace/myapp/rest/application/logs/myapp.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/user/workspace/myapp/rest/application/logs/myapp.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my WorkingDay api in case you see any problem here, maybe... And location of file is /Users//workspace/myapp/rest/application/controllers/api/Workingday.php

```
class Workingday extends REST_Controller {

    public function workingDays_get($id=NULL){
        if($id != NULL){
            $condition['id_working_day'] = $id;
            $workingDays = $this->Working_days->get($condition);
        }else{
            $workingDays = $this->Working_days->get();
        }
        if($workingDays){
            $this->response($workingDays, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }else{
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'No time of day data were found'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is in .htaccess file, but I just can't figure out how to properly configure it. How can I properly configure everything I need in order to be available to develop my application further?

****UPDATE**

I think that visiting `http://myapp.dev/rest/index.php` is working, because its showing Codeigniters 404 page (there is just none initial controller initialized)

[image]

access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2017:17:58:00 +0100] "GET /rest/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1130
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2017:18:00:54 +0100] "GET /rest/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1130
```

while visiting `http://myapp.dev/rest/api/Workingday/workingDay` shows browsers 404 page

[image]

access log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2017:17:53:18 +0100] "GET /rest/api/Workingday/workingDay HTTP/1.1" 404 228
```

Comment: It *might* be that RewriteRule where its taking everything on the url line, and putting it after index.php. So if you tried to goto `http://myapp.dev/rest/api/Workingday/workingDay` it rewrites to `http://myapp.dev/rest/index.php/rest/api/Workingday/workingDay` ... not sure that works. (I am so unfamiliar with codeigniter though)

Comment: no it also not working with index.php in url... I have blank value in configuration $config['index_page']=''

Comment: Well, with that rewrite, if you try to visit `http://myapp.dev/rest/index.php`... it should be changing that to `http://myapp.dev/rest/index.php/rest/index.php` :( Oh... BUT, yeah, that conditional of `!-f` should prevent that. Ok.

Comment: You have lot of frameworks there. Which file and on what location is pointed when you checkout `http://myapp.dev/`?

Comment: http://myapp.dev goes to VUEjs app (root index.html and its working)... if i go http://myapp.dev/admin (opens admin/index.html angular app and its working)... Only problem for now is my /rest app is not working

Comment: When referring to yourself ("I"), please always use a capital letter. Apparently it is common in social media and chatrooms to use a lower-case letter, but here we're keen on readability (hopefully your 141 other questions have not been written in that fashion - it is a lot of work for volunteer editors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly i did, but some how my application sudenly started working...

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rest/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

This is my vhost conf (I think that solved the issue)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myApp.dev
    ServerAlias *.myApp.dev
    ServerAdmin info@myApp.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp"
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp/rest/application/logs/myApp.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp/rest/application/logs/myApp.dev-access_log" common
    <Directory   "/Users/<user>/workspace/myApp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```